# Create WordPress Page that redirects to another URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to create a new WordPress page that is actually a link to another site.  The goal is to have the page show up in a list of my pages, but actually send the web user to the target URL.

For example, say I want to include a page that indicates "My Photos" but actually redirects them to Flickr.

I'm guessing one way to accomplish this is by using a custom template page with a redirect instruction in PHP, but unfortunately I am a newbie to PHP and am not familiar with the way to accomplish this...

Comment: Check out http://bornvirtual.com/wordpress/redirect-404-error-in-wordpress/906/ (from comment by Mazhar)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can accomplish this two ways, both of which need to be done through editing your template files.

The first one is just to add an html link to your navigation where ever you want it to show up.

The second (and my guess, the one you're looking for) is to create a new page template, which isn't too difficult if you have the ability to create a new .php file in your theme/template directory. Something like the below code should do:

```
<?php /*  
Template Name: Page Redirect
*/ 

header('Location: http://www.nameofnewsite.com');
exit();

?>
```

Where the template name is whatever you want to set it too and the url in the header function is the new url you want to direct a user to. After you modify the above code to meet your needs, save it in a php file in your active theme folder to the template name. So, if you leave the name of your template "Page Redirect" name the php file page-redirect.php.

After that's been saved, log into your WordPress backend, and create a new page. You can add a title and content to the body if you'd like, but the important thing to note is that on the right hand side, there should be a drop down option for you to choose which page template to use, with default showing first. In that drop down list, there should be the name of the new template file to use. Select the new template, publish the page, and you should be golden.

Also, you can do this dynamically as well by using the Custom Fields section below the body editor. If you're interested, let me know and I can paste the code for that guy in a new response.

Comment: I think it would be better to use the default WordPress function to make redirections: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: That's a great point Aljullu, but if you're just going to hard code the site URL, why make another call to a function that ultimately just uses the code above? Otherwise, if you're throwing a variable in the mix and need to scrub the URL first, I think you would be correct in using the wp_redirect.

Answer (score 11):

I've found that these problems are often best solved at the server layer.  Do you have access to an .htaccess file where you could place a redirect rule?  If so:

```
RedirectPermanent /path/to/page http://uri.com
```

This redirect will also serve a "301 Moved Permanently" response to indicate that the Flickr page (for example) is the permanent URI for the old page.

If this is not possible, you can create a custom page template for each page in question, and add the following PHP code to the top of the page template (actually, this is all you need in the template:

```
header('Location: http://uri.com, true, 301');
```

[More information about PHP headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Of course, that should be written as: header('Location: http://uri.com', true, 301);

Comment: Here is some more information regarding creating a custom WordPress template: http://www.davidrisley.com/2009/01/20/how-to-custom-page-template-wordpress/

Comment: you mean header('Location: uri.com', true, 301); - :D

Answer (score 11):

Alternately, use a filter.

Create an empty page in your WordPress blog, named appropriately to what you need it to be. Take note of the post_id. Then create a filter that alters its permalink.

```
add_filter('get_the_permalink','my_permalink_redirect');
function my_permalink_redirect($permalink) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID == your_post_id_here) {
        $permalink = 'http://new-url.com/pagename';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

This way the url will show up correctly in the page no funny redirects are required.

If you need to do this a lot, then think about using the custom postmeta fields to define a postmeta value for "offsite_url" or something like that, then you can create pages as needed, enter the "offsite_url" value and then use a filter like the one above to instead of checking the post_id you check to see if it has the postmeta required and alter the permalink as needed.

Comment: Love this config!! I have wordpress that didn't wanted to redirect not even by hosting redirect. This worked a charm!! thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with Wordpress templates, but I'm assuming that headers are sent to the browser by WP before your template is even loaded. Because of that, the common redirection method of:

```
header("Location: new_url");
```

won't work. Unless there's a way to force sending headers through a template before WP does anything, you'll need to use some Javascript like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.location = "new_url";
</script>
```

Put that in the  section and it'll be run when the page loads. This method won't be instant, and it also won't work for people with Javascript disabled.

Comment: Actually, you should be ok to add the header(); to a template if placed right after the php comment code used to name a page template file. Also, any code placed in the active themes function.php file should also execute before WP sends any headers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "raw" plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/
Then it's as simple as:

```
[raw]
<script>
window.location = "http://www.site.com/new_location";
</script>
[/raw]
```

Comment: I don't think wordpress allows javascript in their raw tags now. I'm not sure if they did before.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways of doing this:

1. By changing your `404.php` code.
2. By using wordpress plugins.
3. By editing your `.htaccess` file.

Complete tutorial given at http://bornvirtual.com/wordpress/redirect-404-error-in-wordpress/906/

Comment: I've converted link to comment, the rest is already covered in accepter answer.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that `404.php` could also be a place to add some redirect code. +1

Answer (score 1):

I found a plugin that helped me do this within seconds without editing code:

**https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/**

I found it here: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-link-title-external-url/

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way in wordpress to create a redirection by using wordpress plugins. So here i found a better way through the plugin [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) and also you can find other as well on this site [Create Url redirect in wordpress through Plugin](https://woocanyon.com/create-url-redirect-in-wordpress-through-plugin/)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your link because if the link broken, the answer became useless

Comment: Yeah can we all stop making sites slow and inviting hackers by using plugins for every little thing please? :D

Comment: Stop stacking up plugins for everything, especially such simple stuff. You're asking to get hacked.

Answer (score 0):

(This is for posts, not pages - the principle is same. The permalink hook is different by exact use case)

I just had the same issue and created a more convenient way to do that - where you don't have to re-edit your `functions.php` all the time, or fiddle around with your server settings on each addition (I do not like both).

**TLTR**

You can add a filter on the actual WP permalink function you need (for me it was `post_link`, because I needed that page alias in an archive/category list), and dynamically *read the referenced ID from the alias post itself*.

This is ok, because the post is an alias, so you won't need the content anyways.

**First step** is to open the alias post and put the ID of the referenced post as content
(and nothing else):

[image]

**Next**, open your `functions.php` and add:

```
function prefix_filter_post_permalink($url, $post) {
    // if the content of the post to get the permalink for is just a number...
    if (is_numeric($post->post_content)) {
        // instead, return the permalink for the post that has this ID
        return get_the_permalink((int)$post->post_content);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'prefix_filter_post_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

**That's it**

Now, each time you need to create an alias post, just put the ID of the referenced post as the content, and you're done.

This will just change the permalink. Title, excerpt and so on will be shown as-is, which is usually desired. More tweaking to your needs is on you, also, the "is it a number" part in the `PHP` code is far from ideal, but like this for making the point readable.