# Changing redirect url after post save on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, curl, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem and hoping that there’s some good folks here who can help me. I have prepared a front-end form. This is for a donation form, and I have added a cURL call after the form has submitted, to the payment gateway api. the problem here is, I want the form page to be redirect to a url returned by the payment gateway api, for users to pay with their bank, offsite.

The idea that I have is to change the post permalink after the post have been saved, but before user being redirected, so that they will be redirected to the correct url (given by payment gateway api), and not the original permalink.

Any idea to execute this?

Here’s my code so far:

```
<?php

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 1);

function my_save_post( $post_id ) {

$billplzApi = get_field('billplz_secret_key', 'option');
$billplzId = get_field('billplz_collection_id', 'option');

// bail early if not a donation post
if( get_post_type($post_id) !== 'donation' ) {
    return;
}
// bail early if editing in admin
if( is_admin() ) {  
    return;
}

$post = get_post( $post_id);

$amount = '';
$donationGroup = get_field('donation_amount', $post);
$selectedAmount = $donationGroup['select_donation_amount'];
$customAmount = $donationGroup['specify_any_amount'];

if(!$customAmount){
    $amount = $selectedAmount;
} else {
    $amount = $customAmount;
}

$name = get_field('name', $post);
$email = get_field('email', $post);
$unmobile = get_field('mobile', $post);
$mobile = "+6" . $unmobile;


$billplz_data = array(
      'amount' => $amount * 100,
      'name' => $name,
      'mobile' => $mobile,
      'email' => $email,
      'collection_id' => $billplzId,
      'deliver' => false,
      'description' => 'a test for payment gateway',
      'redirect_url' => home_url('donation-redirect'),
      'callback_url' => home_url('donation-callback')
    );

      $process = curl_init('https://www.billplz.com/api/v3/bills/');
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $billplzApi . ":");
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($billplz_data));
      $return = curl_exec($process);
      curl_close($process);
      $arr = json_decode($return, true);
      //this is the url to replace the original post permalink
      $billplz_url = $arr['url'];       

}

acf_form_head();
get_header();
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">

<?php 

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'new_post'      => array(
                        'post_type'     => 'donation',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'


    ),
    'submit_value'  => 'Donate',
    'html_submit_button' => '<input type="submit" class="acf-button btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" value="%s" />',
    'return' => '%post_url%'
));

endwhile;

?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php 

get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this problem here: [Create WordPress Page that redirects to another URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698797/create-wordpress-page-that-redirects-to-another-url)

so basically i need to add:

```
header('Location:'.$billplz_url);
exit();
```

and remove:

```
'return' => '%post_url%'
```